# How to use external or 3rd party fonts on Windows Phone 8 (WP8)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using external fonts in WP7 project. The project is running on WP7 devices and displays the fonts correctly.

The same app runs on WP8 device, and displays the text correctly, if it is not converted into WP8.

**THE PROBLEM**

I need to convert the project for WP8, in order to use features of WP8. After the conversion, the text is no longer displayed correctly using the external fonts.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Visible" 
           Text="سیدھا راستہ"
           FontFamily="fonts/NafeesNaskhv2.01.ttf#Nafees Naskh v2.01" />
```

**THE QUESTION**

- Is there any known issue in WP8 for using the above syntax?
- Is is allowed to use external fonts on WP8?

Comment: I renamed the font, using font editor to "nafeesnaskh201" (removed spaces). It's still not working after renaming.

Comment: I have a strange observation... Please check out this link https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#folders/0B8xOhdKHzbkySGNvcVAtOTNnc0U... there are two font files "noorehidayat" is working but the other one is not. The problem is on WP8 only. There is no difference in the type of the fonts.

Comment: I found this link on WP developer network http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/8ab921d5-90c1-4f35-853d-8fda8e9bd12c. The problem is not yet solved! No one knows what is it. As Usual MSFT is not responding!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange Answer I found in this case is that Microsoft has created and introduced some fonts for some languages, including Urdu. And they are not supporting other fonts for those particular languages.

Microsoft is explicitly not supporting the other Urdu fonts. It's very strange though!

So, when I changed the font, to the one in the list (follow the link below), it starts to work in WP8. and for WP7 I still have to use the other fonts because the one mentioned here won't work in WP7.

[Font and Language Configuration Support in Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)